# Truncating values before the decimal point

Tags: python, decimal, truncate

I am trying to make a calculator that converts cms into yards, feet, and inches. Example: 127.5 cm is 1 yard, 1 inch, etc. But I am just wondering how I am able to retain the value after the decimal place, is there a way to truncate the number before the decimal place. So if the user inputs a value that results into 3.4231 yards, I want to retain the value ".4231" so that I can convert that into feet, and then the same for inches from feet. Sorry if this is unclear. This is for python 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> 3.4231 % 1
0.4230999999999998
```

Comment: `>>> -3.4231 % 1` yields `0.5769000000000002` (maybe negative numbers are not such a big consideration for physical measures)

Answer (score 2):

Ignacio's answer is good, but if you want it to handle negative numbers, the Python math library offers you `modf`:

```
>>> math.modf(3.4321)[0]
0.43210000000000015
>>> math.modf(-3.4321)[0]
-0.43210000000000015
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the good old-fashioned `value - int(value)`?

Comment: Consider what your algorithm would do if presented with a negative number.

Comment: The result would be negative, but that's easily handled.

Comment: The question was, "What's wrong with..." not "How difficult would it be to fix..."  :)